# Android Generate Shepard Tone on a specific frequency

Tags: android

Can any one suggest if its possible to generate the Shepard Tone/Scale programmatically on Android Platform ?

The only solution I have at the moment is to manipulate several `raw files.wave` using `MediaPlayer`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is definitely possible.

`MediaPlayer` is, as you've probably discovered, suited towards playing media. Prerecorded, streamed, whatever, but always some media from an outside source.

What you are looking for however, is a way to **synthesize** raw PCM sound and stream it in memory to a speaker. For that, have a look at the [AudioTrack](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack) class.

Just do your math, write the audio samples data to a buffer (e.g. a `short[]` array), then write the data to the `AudioTrack`. Finally, `AudioTrack#play`.